# NSURLConnection being called every second is causing a steady increase of used RAM

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I have a timer in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` which calls `checkDNS()` every 1 second.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(refreshFrequencyInt, target: self, selector: Selector("checkDNS"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

and my checkDNS function is as follows:

```
func checkIP() {
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
// there is some code to get API data here but the issue 
// happens even when it is all commented out as seen here.
    })
}
```

So far, nothing is actually happening however when I run my application, I get a constant steady increase of used RAM at about 15mb / minute.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way I should be doing this differently so it isn't using more and more memory?

**EDIT**
It seems like this could be a cache issue, I have tried to put the following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` with no success:

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

**EDIT 2** I've run it through time profiler and it seems the heaviest stack is related to `"HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::ingestTube(Tube*)"` if that helps anyone.

Comment: You create a new operation queue each second, you should use only one operation queue for your DNS requests like NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() or on you create.

Comment: So would I declare a `var queue : NSOperationQueue?` in `AppDelegate`, then initialise it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`  with `queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` and use it in `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue)...` like that?

Comment: It's a solution, if you don't want o use main queue you can also create a queue like your example `queue = NSOperationQueue()` but i'm not sure this is the origin of your memory problems.